# Problem error handling ajax request in Reactjs using fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to do some error handling in my component for a POST request. For some reason the following does not show the alerts. Any Idea's?

Code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Contact extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    message: '',
    email: '', 
    loading: false,
    successMessage: ''
    };
  }

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  /*global fetch */
    fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).then(
        (response) => (response.json())
       ).then((response)=>{

       if (response.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm();
      }else if(response.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
     /*    
     if (response.ok) {
      this.setState({ successMessage: true});
     }
     */
    });
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }

  onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
    <div className="form-group mt-4">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" required aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" required value={this.state.message} onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    { this.state.successMessage &&
      <div className="alert alert-success mt-5" role="alert">
  Your message has been successfully sent. Thanks for your message!
</div> }
    </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Contact;
```

Comment: `catch` won't work ?

Comment: Why do you have got `loading?`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.status === 200){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm();
      }else
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
```

fetch returns 200 for success, not `success`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily like this with a little bit of refractoring using `async/await` and `try/catch` block.

```
async handleSubmit() {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      alert("Message Sent");
      this.resetForm();
      this.setState({ successMessage: true });
    }

    alert("Message failed to send.");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has issue.

```
 if (response.status === 'success'){
    alert("Message Sent."); 
    this.resetForm();
  }else if(response.status === 'fail'){
    alert("Message failed to send.");
  }
```

Response.status returns one of the status codes mentioned [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#statuses). You should check for one of that status integer codes, NOT success/fail

Alternately you can check for [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) which returns a boolean.

So your code will look like

```
   if (response.ok){
    alert("Message Sent."); 
    this.resetForm();
  } else {
    alert("Message failed to send.");
  }
```

NB: [Check](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) for fetch API browser support before using in production. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok)

Comment: Thanks but that did not work, as it only alerts the message failed when the message is going fine and the response is 200 ok